# What makes a thread and a process unique?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, process, cpu

What makes a thread unique from the other threads in the same process and what makes a process unique from other processes? (by unique i mean what makes it different from others?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a programming question. Please rephrase as a programming question. Share some code that is not working and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, it sounds like more of a philosophical question. What makes my laptop screen different from your laptop screen? What makes my cup of coffee different from other cups of coffee in the same office building?

Answer (score 4):

Each thread has its own *[stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)*, and its own *execution context*.  (The stack is the area of memory where the thread stores its local variables, and the execution context is the state of the various CPU registers associated with the thread.  This state gets [loaded in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) to the CPU's hardware registers whenever the thread runs, and saved out to memory whenever the thread is paused to let another thread run instead.)

Each process has its own *[address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space)*.  (The process's address space is a mapping from virtual addresses to physical RAM addresses -- this mapping is handled by the computer's [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and provides the threads within that process with the illusion that they have the computer's RAM all to themselves -- in particular, it is impossible by default for one process to read from or write to the data of another process, because each process's virtual addresses are by default mapped to a separate portion of the computer's physical RAM)

Note that each process will have one or more threads running inside it, and all the threads running inside the same process share the same address space, and thus can read/write each other's data if they choose to.

Comment: First, a thread does not necessarily have a stack. The stack is not a defining characteristic of a thread. Although most threads do have stacks. Second, the stack is really part of the execution context. Third, a thread, at a fundamental level, does not **have** an execution context, it **is** the execution context. Fourth, virtual memory is not technically necessary for multi-programming. Finally, none of this answers the question, which is how are threads and processes distinguished.

Comment: The question asks what makes a thread (or a process) unique, not about how threads and processes are distinguished.  A subtle distinction, I know, but here we are.  As for a thread without a stack, I can imagine such a thing in principle but I have never seen one in real life, have you?

Comment: What's the subtle distinction?

Comment: "How to distinguish two threads" is one way to parse the question -- as Dai indicated in his answer, that's what thread IDs are for.  "What makes a thread unique from other threads" is a bit of a deeper question, i.e. what are all the properties of thread A that make it different from thread B?  That's the question I answered.

Answer (score 2):

Operating systems will assign a unique Thread ID to each thread - and the same for each process: the Process ID, or `pid`. Given that multiple threads in the same process can be otherwise identical (i.e. same entrypoint, same stack contents, same instruction-pointer) it means the Thread ID is the only way to identify a thread. Ditto for processes.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that thread IDs and process IDs are typically just 32-bit integers, that they are typically withdrawn from the same pool of integers, and that an ID can be reused after the the thread/process dies.